# Cloud Functions that add a new collection to the already existing document in firestore

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add new collection to a doc that already  exists in firestore.Is it possible? The following is the code for doing that, I used cloud fucntions for doing that.Whenever a document is created in firestore then the following cloud function has to trigger

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const firestore = new Firestore();
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.myWallet = functions.firestore
    .document('Samyata/{authid}')
        .onCreate(event =>{
        const ID = event.params.authid
        const db = admin.firestore();
        var data = {
        Bitcoins : '0',
        Ether : '0',
        deyaCoins : '0'
        };
        var docRef = db.collection('Samyata').doc(ID);
        var updateDoc = docRef.update({
        db.collection('Samyata').doc(ID).collection('Wallet').doc(ID).set(data);});
        //var updateRef = docRef.update();
        });//end of onCreate()
```

Comment: Remember to always return a promise :) operations on fireste like set, update are returning promises.

Comment: Can u say something on this , I want this structure  db.collection('Samyata').doc(ID).collection('Wallet').doc(ID).set(data);});  in Firestore from client side but we have to press cmd+r to refresh manually and so my cloud functions that trigger on onCreate() method is not working

Comment: onCreate is invoking only one time, whet entity/document is created. If you want to call this more than one time, you need to change onCreate to onUpdate/onWrite.

Comment: Why we have to refresh manually using cmd+r, because firestore need to automatically read the new documents and show itself

Comment: firestore has 2 types of read functions: first one you can use to read data once, second one is for realtime updates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :)

```
return db.collection('Samyata').doc(ID).collection('Wallet').doc(ID).set(data);
```

Comment: hi @Skye, can you please tell me why `return` is needed? I mean, it's a function, `set`, so shouldn't the return be implicit to it? Also, there's no anonymous function declaration inside... please shed some light. Thank you!

Comment: which function is this `return` serving? Thanks!

Comment: @Tudormi return will prevent function from stop. If you will return promise like above, function will executing till timeout or when 'set' operation finishes.

Comment: @Skye it becomes an anonymous function then?
function() {
return db.collection('Samyata').doc(ID).\
collection('Wallet').doc(ID).set(data);
}

Answer (score 1):

or you can concatenate the path like this

```
return db.collection(`Samyata/${ID}/Wallet/${ID}`).add(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
transactionData= {
   TimeStamp: "123",
   SomeBooleanValue: false
}


var addDocToNewCollResult= admin.firestore().collection('CollectionLevel1').doc(userID).collection('CollectionLevel2').doc(transactionID).collection('CollectionLevel3').doc("OtherID").set( transactionData );
```