# Firebase Cloud Function to delete expired posts

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am new to cloud functions as well as JavaScript and having  a hard time achieving the following. I am trying to run a cloud function that reads timestamps from my database and deletes the whole post/node if they are more than 3 minutes old. I have the code below but every time I run it, nothing happens. It always returns "ok" but nothing gets deleted:

```
    const CUT_OFF_TIME = 180000;
    var dbRef = admin.database().ref('/open_windows/{pushId}');
    const now = Date.now();
    const cutoff = now - CUT_OFF_TIME;
    const oldItemsQuery = dbRef.orderByChild('timestamp').endAt(cutoff);

    oldItemsQuery.once('value').then(snapshot => {
        // create a map with all children that need to be removed
        const updates = {};
        snapshot.forEach(child => {
          console.log("adding key: " + child.key)
          updates[child.key] = null;
        });

        // execute all updates in one go and return the result to end the function
        dbRef.update(updates);
        res.status(200).send('ok');
      });

    });
```

My database has the following structure:
[image]

Can someone please assist me and show me where I am going wrong. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand... do you want to remove documents that have this timestamp field *older* than 3 minutes? Or delete the timestamp fields? (in the title you're saying *delete posts* and in the body you're saying *reads timestamps [...] and deletes them*.
Anyway,  why are you using `=null` instead of good old [delete](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data)?

Comment: I want to delete the documents that have the timestamp field older than 3 minutes. I read the timestamp to check which ones are older. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: If you have followed a specific tutorial/example, can you please share it? 

I'm curious how come you are not using `doc('docID').delete()`, like described in the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data

Comment: Im not using firestore, im using the normal realtime database

Comment: OK, thank you and sorry for irrelevant comments

Answer (score 0):

It might be similar to the situation answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47549013/3615567). Try:

`return dbRef.update(updates);`

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial I followed kind of threw me in a ditch. `{pushId}` was the problem, I removed it and now everything works fine.

```
var dbRef = admin.database().ref('/open_windows');
```